# Generate log after every 2 secs

Tags: c++

HI,

I have developed a library in c++ which used to keep track of new and delete operator and generate logs for the same. Now i have to add one more functionality that will generate logs for new and delete after 2 secs and everey 2 secs it will refresh the log file. so that if the main program gets core dump then also we can have some logs to track memomy allocation. Any help woild be appreciated.

thanx in advance.

Comment: Put a global static timer to check for a lapse of 2 seconds, inside a global static function, and then only log else don't.

Answer (score 0):

Just write to some buffer and store timestamp of last dump to disk, if more then 2 seconds ago dump the buffer again and reset timestamp. But if you want this log for debug even when a crash occurs I assume you can lose vital information in those 2 seconds, maybe you could write every new/delete without the 2 second delay when running in debug mode.

Answer (score 0):

For a computer program, 2 seconds is an awfully long time and a lot of allocations/deallocations can happen in that time that don't get logged if the main program crashes.

A better alternative would be to log information about every allocation and deallocation to some persistent storage (a file for example). This might result in a huge amount of data being logged, so you should only enable/activate the feature when debugging a potentially memory-related problem, but it has the advantage that a core dump does not cause you to lose that much information (at most one buffer worth, if you are using buffered IO) and you can let some off-line analysis tools loose on the logs to locate potential problems for you (or just to filter out the majority of obviously correct allocation/deallocation pairs).

Answer (score 0):

There are tools for verifying memory access correctness, such as `valgrind`.  Have you looked at them yet?  If not, you should--if you plan to do this sort of logging for every single allocation, it's going to slow your program down a lot, just like those already-written tools will do.  If you need something a lot more precision-targeted, then maybe writing your own is a good idea.